# How would $\operatorname{ir}(G)=\operatorname{r}(G)$ imply that minimal dominating is maximal irredundant?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I've read about domination theory, but I have a doubt/commentary about the following exercise from *Graphs and Digraphs, 4th edition* by Chartrand and Lesniak.

> Let $G$ be a graph with $\operatorname{ir}(G)=\operatorname{r}(G)$ (domination number equals to irredundance number). Prove that if $S$ is a minimal dominating set then $S$ is maximal irredundant.

I think that minimal dominating is maximal irredundant, independent whether $\operatorname{ir}(G)=\operatorname{r}(G)$. So I do not understand why this hypothesis helps or how it can be used into some proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please replace "Another mistake" in the title by a less offensive formulation.